# Angular getting Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider

Tags: angularjs

In below screenshot I am working on a tab called ICD Group. I have created its service, controller and html but when I click ICD Group tab then I get below error. Below screen is a html in which we have 4 ng-click:

```
Error: $injector:unpr
Unknown Provider
Unknown provider: $uibModalProvider <- $uibModal <- rpmICDGroupController

angular.js:13642 Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/$injector/unpr?p0=%24uibModalProvider%20%3C-%20%24uibModal%20%3C-%20rpmICDGroupController
    at http://www.agemr.com:9100/mobiledoc/jsp/webemr/js/angularjs/angular.min.js:6:412
    at http://www.agemr.com:9100/mobiledoc/jsp/webemr/js/angularjs/angular.min.js:43:84
    at Object.d [as get] (http://www.agemr.com:9100/mobiledoc/jsp/webemr/js/angularjs/angular.min.js:40:344)
    at http://www.agemr.com:9100/mobiledoc/jsp/webemr/js/angularjs/angular.min.js:43:146
    at d (http://www.agemr.com:9100/mobiledoc/jsp/webemr/js/angularjs/angular.min.js:40:344)
    at e (http://www.agemr.com:9100/mobiledoc/jsp/webemr/js/angularjs/angular.min.js:41:78)
    at Object.invoke (http://www.agemr.com:9100/mobiledoc/jsp/webemr/js/angularjs/angular.min.js:41:163)
    at P.instance (http://www.agemr.com:9100/mobiledoc/jsp/webemr/js/angularjs/angular.min.js:89:399)
    at n (http://www.agemr.com:9100/mobiledoc/jsp/webemr/js/angularjs/angular.min.js:65:10)
    at g (http://www.agemr.com:9100/mobiledoc/jsp/webemr/js/angularjs/angular.min.js:58:429) <div ng-include="rpmicdGroupTab" class="ng-scope">
```

rpmAdminIcdGroupService.js

```
angular.module('rpm.rpmIcdGroupService',[]).factory('rpmIcdGroupService', function($http) {
// My service code goes here
}
```

rpmAdminIcdGroupController.js

```
    var rpmAdminDependancies = ['oc.lazyLoad', 'rpm.rpmIcdGroupService','ecw.pagination','ecw.dir.scrollpane'];
    var rpmAdminModule = angular.module('rpmAdminICDGroup', rpmAdminDependancies);
    rpmAdminModule.controller('rpmICDGroupController',['$scope', '$ocLazyLoad', '$uibModal', 'rpmIcdGroupService',
    function($scope, $ocLazyLoad, $uibModal, rpmIcdGroupService) {
    
     //My controller code goes here
    
}]);
```

rpmIcdGroup.html:

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="orangetheme" ng-controller="rpmICDGroupController">
// html code for icd group goes here
</body>
</html>
```

rpmAdminDashboard.html: Please note loadICDGroup() calls the rpmAdminDashboardController

```
<div class="orangetheme" ng-app="rpmApp" ng-controller="rpmController" ng-init = "rpmAdminInit()"  style="background-color: white;height: 700px;width: 100%">
<!-- other code -->
    <ul class="nav">
                                        <li ng-click="deviceTypeMethodName"><a href="#device-settings-tab" data-toggle="tab">Device Type Settings</a></li>
                                        <li ng-click="loadICDGroup()"><a href="#icd-group-tab" data-toggle="tab">ICD Group</a></li>
                                        <li ng-click="loadRpmInsurances()"><a href="#insurances-tab" data-toggle="tab">Insurances</a></li>
                                        <li ng-click="generalSettingsMethodName"><a href="#general-settings-tab" data-toggle="tab">General Settings</a></li>
                                    </ul>
```

rpmAdminDashBoardController.js

```
var rpmAdminDependancies = ['oc.lazyLoad', 'rpm.rpmInsuranceService', 'rpm.rpmIcdGroupService'];
var rpmAdminModule = angular.module('rpmApp', rpmAdminDependancies);
rpmAdminModule.controller('rpmController',['$scope','$ocLazyLoad','rpmInsuranceService', 'rpmIcdGroupService','$rootScope',
    function($scope , $ocLazyLoad, rpmInsuranceService, rpmIcdGroupService) {

        $scope.loadICDGroup = function(){
            $ocLazyLoad.load({
                name : 'rpmAdminICDGroup',
                files : [
                    '/mobiledoc/jsp/webemr/ccmr/rpm/rpminsurance/js/controller/rpmAdminIcdGroupController.js'
                ]
            }).then(function() {
                $scope.rpmicdGroupTab ='';
                $scope.rpmicdGroupTab = '/mobiledoc/jsp/webemr/ccmr/rpm/rpminsurance/html/rpmIcdGroup.html';
            }, function(e) {
                console.log(e);
            });
        };

    }]);
```

[image: My html code shows up on screen]

Answer (score 0):

This error generally means you either forgot to register a service/controller/component *or* if you are using another module in your app you forgot to register that module as a dependency. This time it is the latter: `angular.module('rpm.rpmIcdGroupService',[])`, that empty array means you never registered any of the `ui.xxx` modules as a dependency of your module. As you are using the dialog you need to register module `'ui.bootstrap'`.

```
var rpmAdminModule = angular.module('rpm.rpmIcdGroupService',['ui.bootstrap'])
```

Don't forget you also need a reference to this module's script file either included in your build or in the html page as a script reference. Which one depends on how you are shipping your app.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this error occurs when you are registering angular.module('yourAppName',[]) more than once in your application. You have to register module once like angular.module('yourAppName', []) and then get it by angular.module('yourAppName'). For more information you can visit this link as well: http://www.onemorecommit.com/2015/10/27/fixing-angular-injector-unpr-unknown-provider/. try this and comment if the problem still persist.